# Ajax - secureimage - captcha not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using secureimage to validate a captcha.    I think I am doing things they way they should be done, but I may be missing a big point.  I am neither a jQuery guru nor an AJAX guru.

I have a form that passes data to a script to send a thank you email.  At the top of the thankYou.php script there is a check against the captcha (using secureimage).  It works if I simply submit the form to the PHP.  The PHP can properly determine if the captcha is the correct one.  If it fails, I can return back to my page.  No problems there.  What I wanted to do is check the captcha first using AJAX and then if it passes submit the same captcha to the thankYou.php script so I can capture a failed captcha without submitting the form.

I can successfully use AJAX to ask a PHP script if the captcha was correct.

My problem is if I first do the AJAX call and there is a failure, perfect I'm done.  If successful, I need to send the captcha to my thankYou.php script to validate before sending the email.  Sorry I am long winded.  I guess ONE, can I validate the same captcha twice and TWO, if I can't what is a better way to do this?  Thanks for whatever suggestions you may have.

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**
***I'm not sure why I did not go straight to this.  I am now sending the captcha to the thank you email code via AXAJ.  If the captcha fails, I don't send an email and I return an error code.  If the captcha is successful, I send the email and return appropriate completion code.  Silly I didn't think of this first.***

```
<!-- HTML CODE -->
<form action="ThankYou.php" method="post" id="thankYou">
    <img id="captcha" src="securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" /><br />         
    Enter Text:<br />
    <input type="text" name="captcha_code" size="6" maxlength="6" required />
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false"></span><img src="securimage/images/refresh.png" alt="refresh the Captcha image" height=25 width=25/></a>
    <input type="button" value="submit" class="darkButton" id="contactInfo" onclick="submitTheForm()" />
</form>

/* Javascript Code */
function submitTheForm() {
    checkCaptcha(function(data) {
        if (data=="true") {
            document.getElementById("thankYou").submit();
        }
        else {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}

function checkCaptcha(callBack) {      
    return $.ajax({
      url: 'check_captcha.php',
      data: {cc: $( "input[name='captcha_code']" ).val()},
      dataType: "json",
      type: 'post'
    }).done(callBack)
}

/* PHP CODE */
/* thankYou.php */
<?php
session_start();
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ACC/securimage/securimage.php';
$securimage = new Securimage();

if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
   $myVariable = "";
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $myVariable = $myVariable . $key . "-" . $value . " | ";
    }
    print($myVariable);
    exit;
}

/* check_captcha.php */
<?php
session_start();
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ACC/securimage/securimage.php';
$securimage = new Securimage();

if ($securimage->check($_POST['cc']) == false) {
  $return = "false";
}
else {
  $return = "true";
}

die(json_encode($return));  

?>
```